# AWS lambda pipline errors

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am having pipline errors that I have no idea how to resolve.

In my console I do get such warning:

```
==== node_password ====
Severity      High
Message       A hardcoded password in plain text is identified. Store it properly in an environment variable.
Description   A hardcoded password in plain text is identified. Store it properly in an environment variable.
Identifiers  
              node_password
              None
              CWE-798
              None
File          packages/web/.serverless_nextjs/api-lambda/chunks/3779.js
Line          12677
```

I did check my chunk file, I was able to find this one, and there is no password hardcoded in my code.

What I can do to avoid this issue?
Also I do not have access to customer AWS lambda so not sure what they have configured

Comment: Where do you get such an error? Lambda itself does not care what you do in your code.

Comment: this is from gitlab node-scan SAST

Comment: Then you should probably tag those things instead of AWS.